# Code::Blocks - Linux - prints "Hello World" even though it isn't in the "main.cpp" file

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, archlinux

I have recently started a few projects to help me learn C++, I am creating a program that allows the user to enter a grade score /100, the code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main (gradeScore)
{
    int gradeScore
    cout << "Enter your grade score out of 100"
    cin >> gradeScore

    if (gradeScore == 100)
    {
        cout << "Well done! You have achieved a perfect score!.."
    {
}
```

I tried compiling it just to make sure that it was working so far, however, it opens up the terminal and prints

```
Hello World! 

Process returned 0 (0x0)    execution time : 0.013 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

I'm not sure what to do about it, there's nowhere in the project that contains the string "Hello World" anywhere. Could someone please help me? I just want to be able to carry on my learning without and hinderance like this.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 rev 9501 (2013-12-25 18:25:45) gcc 4.8.2 Linux/unicode - 32 bit (not sure if this is helpful)

Thanks guys.

Comment: are you absolutely sure you rebuilt? and are running the correct executable?

Comment: Is that valid C++ code? There is not such main() version  - int main(int) - you can use...what are you executing?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti good point. looking at this again, this code doesnt compile at all, so he is most likely running an old executable

Comment: `int main (gradeScore)` is not valid c++. You are not running the code you posted. You are running a previous program.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  I've literally just been following the C++ for dummies (queue laughs) and the learncpp website. I'm a bit of a noob with compiling and I've had nothing but trouble with it since trying it out. I still don't understand where "Hello World!" has come from, or what I'm doing wrong haha.

Comment: I've tried adding the semi-colons into the code too (just noticed I forgot to put them in) and still no luck! @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: @MarcFreeman you need to get your code to compile before you can run it.  Concentrate on that first, then worry about why the wrong program is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to thank you for your advice and help, I'm sure it's frustrating seeing questions like this all the time off us noobs.

I have solved the problem and it turns out the solution was stupidly easy: 
I deleted the project, made a new one, opened the main.cpp file and found this cheeky little bugger sitting on the file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" <<endl;
}
```

I deleted it and corrected my original program to this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gradeScore;
    cout << "Input test score out of 100:";
    cin >> gradeScore;

    if (gradeScore == 100)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations! You achieved a perfect score" << endl; 
    {
}
```

Again, thank you for your patience guys! I promise I'm trying hahaha!